# How to solve conda update --all resulting "Unsatisfiable package specifications" error

Tags: python, anaconda

This is the error I'm getting

[image: error]

I did as the thing suggested and got out the info on the installed versions of `pykit` and `bottleneck`.

Here is `pykit`:

[image: pykit info]

Here is `bottleneck`:

[image: bottleneck]

I figured, `pykit` uses `numpy 1.8` whereas `bottleneck` lists `numpy 1.10` as a dependency. `numpy` installed is version 1.10. I don't exactly know what those packages do so I didn't want to mess around by removing packages.

One guide on the Continuum Developer blog said to run the command `conda remove anaconda`. That hasn't helped. (edit) As you can see:

[image]

I still get the same error. So what is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: `conda update --all` has been substantially enhanced as of conda `4.0`.  Can you run `conda update conda` and see if your issue persists?